# Width Error in eclipse

Tags: android, attributes, width

I'm trying to develop my first app and I'm receiving the following error:-

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#F0A0A0A0"/>
    <stroke android:width="2dp" color="#A00080FF"/>
    <padding android:left="5dp" android:top="0dp"
        android:right="5dp" android:bottom="1dp" />
</shape>
```

It says on the width line above " attribute is missing the android namespace prefix"

Can anybody please help?

Comment: first specify shape attribute....

Answer (score 4):

your problem is not width but colour. It should be fully qualified

```
 android:color="#A00080FF"
```

Answer (score 1):

You code should be like.
Replace `color` with `android:color`

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#F0A0A0A0"/>
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#A00080FF"/>
    <padding android:left="5dp" android:top="0dp"
        android:right="5dp" android:bottom="1dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please specify **android:color** instead of just **color**.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use color individually.
Instead, use

```
android:color="#A00080FF"
```